# Implementing custom foreach in order to better understand types and function composition

Tags: scala

In order to try and understand Scala's type system I'm attempting
to implment a custom implementation for List.foreach method :

```
package com

object customForEach extends App {

  class customForEach[B, A] extends Iterable[A] with collection.Seq[A] {

    def foreach[B](f: A ⇒ B) {
      var these = this
      while (!these.isEmpty) {
        f(these.head)
        these = these.tail
      }
    }

    def tail = this match {
      case h :: t ⇒ t

    }
  }
}
```

When I complile this code I receive errors :

```
[error] \Desktop\Scala\src\main\scala\typeparam.scala:16: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.::[B(in class ::)]
[error]  required: com.customForEach.customForEach[B(in class customForEach),A]
[error]       case h :: t ? t
[error]              ^
[error] \Desktop\Scala\src\main\scala\typeparam.scala:16: not found: value t
[error]       case h :: t ? t
[error]                     ^
[error] \Desktop\Scala\src\main\scala\typeparam.scala:11: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[A]
[error]  required: com.customForEach.customForEach[B,A]
[error]         these = these.tail
[error]                       ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed 31-Jan-2015 11:53:40
```

In particular I find it iteresting how println can be composed with List in this fashion : `List(1,2,3).foreach(println)`

Do I need to add extend another trait in order to access the .tail function ?

For this error :

```
not found: value t
    [error]       case h :: t ? t
```

Shouldn't `t` be found since it is created using pattern match operator `::` ?

Comment: Why are you redefining tail? Iterable already defines this function. The pattern match may go wrong because it is not a List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons why this code won't work. In order to understand the first compiler error `not found: value t`, you must look at the error immediately before it. `::` exists solely for `List`, but here you do not have a `List`, only `Iterable with Seq`. That pattern match can't work, which causes `t` to become "not found".

There are even larger problems than that, though. Even if you remove your definition of `tail` (which is unnecessary), you'll then find that you're missing abstract method definitions for `apply`, `iterator`, and `length` from the `Seq` trait. I imagine you're doing this because you can't extend `List`, which is sealed. You can copy the implementations of `apply`, and `length` from `LinearSeqOptimized`, then easily implement an `iterator` method, but there's still another problem: your class does not have a constructor.

Okay, well we'll look at what `List` does again. `List` is abstract and has two sub-types, `::` and `Nil`. `Nil` is just a case object, and `::` has a constructor that accepts the `head` and `tail` of the `List`. This isn't going to help you very much, unless you also want to duplicate the code for `::` and `Nil` as well.

Scala collections are very large complicated beasts, and extending them to override one method is not a simple process.

Comment: thank you for the detail, the more I delve into types the more I realize I don't understand